# core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

While implementing Lazy Loading Routing Modules, i am facing following error in console

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at getChildConfig (router.js:3045)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.processSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js:3017)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.processSegment (router.js:2976)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.processSegmentAgainstRoute (router.js:3026)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.processSegment (router.js:2976)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.processSegmentGroup (router.js:2961)
    at Recognizer.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Recognizer.recognize (router.js:2938)
    at recognize (router.js:2924)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.js:3767)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:60)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Please let me know if extra information is needed. I tried to find resolution since much time but no luck.

Comment: I removed wildCard Routing code as follows and it worked.

{
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: '../floating-banner/floating-banner.module#FloatingBannerModule' 
  }

What could be the reason for that ??

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned above is removed post removing wild card entry from the route.

What seems issue in following wild card code ?

{
path: '**',
loadChildren: '../floating-banner/floating-banner.module#FloatingBannerModule'
}